# Store Lucene index file to remote location

Tags: c#, .net, lucene, lucene.net

Hi
Is there a way to store lucene index files to remote location for example I'm on PC(A) and want to index my documents but store the result to remote location like some directory on PC(B) is it supported internally or i should write custom code to support it ?

many thanks to accurate response

Answer (score 6):

There are several options available, depending on your network setup.

You can work directly against a remote filesystem published as a network shares with `FSDirectory.Open(@"\\server\index")`, but as already been noted, network latency and speed will affect your indexing.

You could also index it locally, either using a `FSDirectory` or a `RAMDirectory`, and call `Directory.Copy(src, dest, closeDirSrc)` to transfer it via a network share to your remote location. This will be faster than working directly against a remote directory since there's no network overhead during indexing.

If speed is of no concern, or you're feeling adventurous, try building a custom directory implementation (inherit from `Directory`) which uses whatever transfer technique you need (ftp, email, carrier pigeons, etc).

Answer (score 1):

1. I'm not sure how you're connecting to the "remote location", but if you can mount PC(B) as part of your filesystem you can put your index there without doing anything special.
2. That being said, remote filesystems are [slower](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ImproveSearchingSpeed) than local ones

Comment: you mean creating mapping drive for remote directory ? if remote file system is not a good solution what would i do if i have multiple indexer on different systems and a searcher to feed search request

Comment: @Ehsan: My suggestion would be to use Solr rather than trying to replicate its distributed searching functionality. Apart from that, you don't have very many options.